# Stream BigQuery table into Google Pub/Sub

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Google bigQuery Table and I want to stream the entire table into pub-sub Topic

what should be the easy/fast way to do it?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really depends on the size of the table.

If it's a small table (a few thousand records, a couple doze columns) then you could setup a process to query the entire table, convert the response into a JSON array, and push to pub-sub.

If it's a big table (millions/billions of records, hundreds of columns) you'd have to export to file, and then prepare/ship to pub-sub

It also depends on your partitioning policy - if your tables are set up to partition by date you might be able to, again, query instead of export.

Last but not least, it also depends on the frequency - is this a one time deal (then export) or a continuous process (then use table decorators to query only the latest data)?

Need some more information if you want a truly helpful answer.

**Edit**

Based on your comments for the size of the table, I think the best way would be to have a script that would:

1. Export the table to [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) as newline delimited JSON
2. Process the file (read line by line) and send to pub-sub

There are [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries) for most programming languages. I've done similar things with Python, and it's fairly straight forward.

Comment: the table have 3M row and ~7 columns

Comment: one time upload, or continuous?

Comment: it is not continuous but i would like to do it once in a while.. :)

Comment: the question is about streaming, which is not addressed in this answer. Please see Felipe's answer which is the correct one imo

Answer (score 12):

**2019 update:**

Now it's really easy with a click-to-bigquery option in Pub/Sub:

[image]

Find it on: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topicList

---

The easiest way I know of is going through Google Cloud Dataflow, which natively knows how to access BigQuery and Pub/Sub.

In theory it should be as easy as the following Python lines:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
tablerows = p | 'read' >> beam.io.Read(
  beam.io.BigQuerySource('clouddataflow-readonly:samples.weather_stations'))
tablerows | 'write' >> beam.io.Write(
  beam.io.PubSubSink('projects/fh-dataflow/topics/bq2pubsub-topic'))
```

This combination of Python/Dataflow/BigQuery/PubSub doesn't work today (Python Dataflow is in beta, but [keep an eye on the changelog](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-python)).

We can do the same with Java, and it works well - I just tested it. It runs either locally, and also in the hosted Dataflow runner:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

PCollection<TableRow> weatherData = p.apply(
        BigQueryIO.Read.named("ReadWeatherStations").from("clouddataflow-readonly:samples.weather_stations"));
weatherData.apply(ParDo.named("tableRow2string").of(new DoFn<TableRow, String>() {
    @Override
    public void processElement(DoFn<TableRow, String>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        c.output(c.element().toString());
    }
})).apply(PubsubIO.Write.named("WriteToPubsub").topic("projects/myproject/topics/bq2pubsub-topic"));

p.run();
```

Test if the messages are there with:

```
gcloud --project myproject beta pubsub subscriptions  pull --auto-ack sub1
```

---

**Hosted Dataflow screenshot:**

[image: Hosted Dataflow at work]

Comment: Do you have the full script of this example available on github? I am interested in deploying the inverse of this from pub/sub to bigquery. thanks

Comment: It's like a batch, but the looking option for streaming the bigquery data to pub/sub.